# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{x}{i} -\operatorname{Log}\left ( 1+\frac{x}{i} \right )\right )$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

How to show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{x}{k}  -\operatorname{Log}\left ( 1+\frac{x}{k} \right )\right )
$$
converges uniformly for $x$ in compact subsets of $x\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re x>0$? Here $\operatorname{Log}$ denoted the principal logarithm.

If $x>0$, we we can use  $1-1/x\leq \log x$ to show that the $k$'th term in the series is less than $x^2/k^2$ for alle $x>0$, and so it clearly converges uniformly on compact sets for $x>0$. But, what about the case $x\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re x>0$?

Initially, I was thinking about looking at the imaginary part of the series, as the real part is already done. But, how does the imaginary part of this expression look like?

Comment: If the real part is >0, I think you should be able to expand Log in a simple power sequence and then be able to bound the general term on the series by something

Comment: if $x \in K$ then $|x| \le M_K$ so for $k \ge 2M_k$ say so $|x/k| \le 1/2, x \in K$, one can use the powers series of $\log (1+x/k)$ and simple estimates to show that $|\log (1+x/k)-x/k| \le (2M)^2/k^2$ etc

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the nice estimate! Shouldn't it be $|\log (1+x/k)-x/k| \le M^2/k^2$ for all $x\in K$ and $k\geq 2M$?

Comment: does it matter? as long as you have an estimate of the type $|\log (1+x/k)-x/k| \le c_K/k^2, x \in K, k$ large enough depending on $K$ you are good